# performance issue when adding vector layers to openLayers map where it's consuming too much memory/GPU usage when upgrading to v.6 and v.7

Tags: openlayers

I was updating Openlayer from version 5 to version 7 since I use it for my web application and it seems I'm experiencing performance issues where it consumes too much memory and GPU power.
I tried using vector image layer rather than vector layer, but there was no difference.
Additionally, my web application requires over 200 vector layers, all of which were functional in version 5, but in versions 6 and 7, it completely stalls (where it's affecting the zooming and mouse event functionality).
any advice on this matter?

Comment: You almost certainly don't need 200 layers as there is no way for users to handle that much information. If you are pulling down 200 WFS layers then I'm not surprised it goes slowly. Use WMS for large numbers of layers/features.

Comment: @IanTurton my problem is not with geoserver or the time it takes to fetch the data, the issue is with adding multiple vector layers to my map. while on ol v.5 works perfectly the olv.6 and v.7 don't .

Comment: that's why I removed the geoserver tag

Comment: Same issue as described here maybe https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14171

Comment: @BR75 Thank you very much !!!,  I was using className property for my vectorLayers, so i removed it and set my own class_name property inside property attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using classname property inside my vectorLayer in which it will create a new full canvas for each layer,
VectorLayer({className : string ,
Source : vectorSource }).
So I just Removed it and now it works perfectly.